# Can the definition of almost periodic functions be simplified?

Tags: functional-analysis, almost-periodic-functions

A bounded continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is almost periodic if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $L>0$, such that every interval of $\mathbb{R}$ with length $\ge L$ contains some real number $T$ such that $\Vert f(\cdot+T)-f \Vert_\infty \le \epsilon$.

An equivalent definition is the relative compactness of the set of all functions
$f(\cdot+T)$ with $T$ varying in $\mathbb{R}$ in the space of all continuous bounded functions endowed with $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$.

It is necessary to have
$$\liminf_{T \to \infty} \Vert f(\cdot+T)-f \Vert_\infty = 0.$$
Is it also sufficient?

My thought: the triangle inequality and the invariance of the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ under translations show that the function $T \mapsto \Vert f(\cdot+T)-f \Vert_\infty$ is sub-additive on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: What norm is this?

Comment: Usual $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ norm on the space of all continuous bounded functions. I edited the post.

Comment: It might help if you'd link a pdf where your quasiperiodic is defined.

Comment: I recall the two equivalent definitions in my post.

Comment: Isn't the "necessary" part obvious? I might be missing something.

Comment: The sufficient part sounds hard at first glance (if it's true), you'd need show that assuming there exists some shifts that there have to be linearly many shifts. (I might be misunderstanding something.)

Comment: For the sufficient part: If you get one shift and then shift again by that shift best you can do is $2\epsilon$. This obviously can't go on since you are guaranteed to have some bigger shift that works so there has to be some cancellation... Hmm...

Comment: Oh my bad, I've read "Is it" instead of "It is" on the "necessary" part. Nice question, +1!

Comment: I am thinking about a counterexample, namely, when the function $f(x)$ is like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2}\left(1+\sin\frac x{2^n}\right)$.

Comment: Adding some more tags to this might help get it seen.

Comment: @AlexRavsky A uniform limit of generalized trigonometric polynomials is almost periodic.

Comment: Someone post a solution to this please else I can't sleep tonight!

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Could you show some non trivial properties of a function satisfying your definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "No". Just take a hump at $0$ and place copies of it on the line along a finite arithmetic progression with some big difference slowly scaling it down to $0$. Then take the whole resulting picture and place copies of it on the line along a (longer) finite arithmetic progression with much bigger difference even more slowly scaling it down to $0$. And so on. You'll get a function with your properties that is identically $0$ on arbitrarily long intervals, which is, clearly, not almost-periodic.

By eulersgroupie's request here is a formula. Let $\psi$ be your favorite bump on $[-1,1]$. Choose a sequence of numbers $T_j$ going up really fast. Now put
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=(k_1,\dots)}\prod_{j\ge 1}\left(1-\tfrac{|k_j|}{j}\right)_+\psi(x+\sum_j k_jT_j)
$$
where the first summation is taken over sequences $k$ having only finitely many integer non-zero entries and $x_+=\max(x,0)$.

Comment: Why does this function satisfy the liminf condition?

Comment: @eulersgroupie Shift by the differences of the corresponding progressions.

Comment: Let's say you shift by the second progression, what guarantees that the humps from the first progression get matched well?

Comment: @eulersgroupie The *whole picture* gets shifted by the second progression. Just take paper and draw the first two iterations :-)

Comment: @eulersgroupie If it is still hard to comprehend what's going on, I can write a formula, but IMHO, the picture is clearer :)

Comment: Well I have to admit I do not see your idea as of right now. A formula would clarify things.

Comment: @eulersgroupie Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks! It's a nice formula :) And it works :) Is way more clear than your text!

Comment: @eulersgroupie It is an *exact* translation of my text. But yeah, some people prefer pictures and some prefer formulas. We just belong to opposite categories :-)

Comment: No, I prefer words but I didn't get your words.

Comment: @eulersgroupie Not words. Pictures. You were supposed to draw according to the instructions :-). But nevermind; the message went through and that is all that matters.

Comment: You provided a text not a picture and I didn't understand your text. That's why we have formulas :)

Comment: @eulersgroupie Good point. OK, maybe I'll add a picture too, but not now :-)

Comment: Btw I did understand your text AFTER you posted your pretty formula :)

Comment: @fedja Thank you for your answer. It looks interesting. Let me think about it.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Notice that only one term in the sum is nonzero for a specific $x$. The finiteness of the arithmetic progressions is encoded in the brackets with the $+$ and the decay is encoded in the product. So around a big progression $T_j$ we have all the smaller finite progressions and if we shift by $T_j$ all the smaller ones get shifted as well and the difference is between $0$ and $1/j$ times the hump at $x$ (maximal difference appears right on the finite progression $T_j$ and the difference is smaller on it's clones coming from the bigger finite progressions).

Comment: With all the smaller finite progessions I mean the clones of them (around each smaller finite progression there is again each even smaller finite progression around them...(until you reach the smallest one)). Kinda awkward in words, thinking about it now I think fedja has done a great job in explaining his idea in words.

Comment: Thank fedja and user1279061 for your explanations. I have validates fedja's answer. And I give more details in a answer which formalizes her arguments. n

Answer (score 0):

Reformulation of an example of the answer given by fedja.

Start from $f_0$ given $f_0(x)=(1-|x|)_+$, with compact support $[-1,1]$.

The function $f_1 := \displaystyle{\sum_{k=-1}^1} \Big(1-\Big|\frac{k}{2}\Big|\Big)_+ f_0(\cdot-2k)$ has compact support $[-3,3]$.

The function $f_2 = \displaystyle{\sum_{k=-2}^2} \Big(1-\Big|\frac{k}{3}\Big|\Big)_+ f_1(\cdot-6k)$, has compact support $[-15,15]$.

Assume that $f_n$ has support $[-P_n,P_n]$ where $P_n = \prod_{k=0}^n(2k+1)$.

Then the function $f_{n+1} = \displaystyle{\sum_{k=-n-1}^{n+1}} \Big(1-\Big|\frac{k}{n+2}\Big|\Big)_+ f_{n-1}(\cdot-2P_nk)$ has support $[-P_{n+1},P_{n+1}]$.

Since $f_{n+1}$ and $f_n$ coincide on $[-P_n,P_n]$, and since these intervals are larger and larger,  the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on compacts sets to some continuous function $f$.

By recursion we check that $||f_n||_\infty = f_n(0) = 1$ for all $n$. Thus $||f||_\infty \le 1$.

Using that $k \mapsto (1-|k|/(n+2))_+$ is Lipschitz with ration $1/(n+2)$, we derive that
$$||f_{n+1}(\cdot+P_n)-f_{n+1}||_\infty \le 1/(n+2)||f_n||_\infty = 1/(n+2).$$
More generally $||f_m(\cdot+P_n)-f_m||_\infty \le 1/(n+2)$ for all $m \ge n+1$, because $f_m$ is a sum of functions with disjoint supports (up to the boundaries) which are shifts of $f_{n+1}$. Hence $||f(\cdot+P_n)-f||_\infty \le 1/(n+2)$.

Yet, $f$ is not almost periodic. For example, the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $|f(x)| \ge 1/2$ contains no point in arbitrary long intervals.